# How to setup Asus Rog Zephyrus Keyboard on Hyprland

Tags: linux, configuration, keyboard, nixos, wayland

I'm quite new to [NixOS](https://nixos.org/) and I'm trying to set up my laptop using [Hyprland](https://hyprland.org/).

The problem is that I cannot get my keyboard to work properly. Some keys don't return anything when pressed (I tested it with xev). In particular, the following keys are not functioning:

- Volume (+/-)
- Mic mute/unmute
- ROG key
- Volume mute

I've tried setting `services.xserver.xkbModel` to `pc105` and `asus_laptop`, but nothing seems to work.

Here's my configuration:

- **OS**: NixOS 23.05.2064.53657afe297 (Stoat) x86_64
- **Host**: ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC. GA401QC
- **Kernel**: 6.1.38
- **Shell**: bash 5.2.15
- **DE**: Hyprland (Wayland)
- **WM**: sway
- **Terminal**: foot

```hs
services.xserver.enable = true;
services.xserver = {
  layout = "fr";
  xkbVariant = "azerty";
};
```

Any hints would be greatly appreciated. Thank you very much. If you need more information or if I'm not clear, feel free to ask.

EDIT: Some DEs are ables to detect these keys (GNOME and Plasma at least) but I cannot find out why.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you found solutions yet. I just did a Hyprland installation on Arch last week on my ROG Zephyrus G14 GA401I. So here is what I did.

I think you have to use wev for wayland compositors to get the correct keycodes under Hyprland. You will also need to install pactl, brightnessctl, asusctl, rog-control-center, supergfxctl.

Here is a link to my hyprland.conf for my ROG Zephyrus G14 GA401I tweaked to my preference. Hope this helps. (Look under ROG Zephyrus G14GA401I)
https://github.com/fphchen/dotfiles/blob/main/configs/hypr/hyprland.conf

I am sure there are other better solutions, but this is what I end up with.